# How to reverse strings in python by word

Tags: python, if-statement, reverse

This is my code so far, but I am trying to display  olleH,dlroW instead of dlroW, olleH (Hello World). What is wrong with my code. Also i've seen examples that use for statements to reverse a string. But I would like to stick to if else statements (recursion).

```
def reverse_recursion(string):
    if len(string) == 0:
        return string
    else:
        return reverse_recursion(string[1:]) + string[0]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `[::-1]` to reverse the string. So for it example could look like:

```py
def reverse(string):
   if len(string) == 0:
      return string
   else:
      words = string.split()
      new_string = ""

      for word in words:
         new_string += word[::-1] + " "

      return new_string
```

Or if you would not like to use a `for` loop then you can use the following code:

```py
def reverse(string):
    if len(string) == 0:
        return string
    else:
        words = string.split()
        new_string = " ".join(list(map(lambda word: word[::-1], words)))

        return new_string
```

Comment: Hello, isn't for word in words: a for in / for statement.

Comment: @Kotchi It is a `for` loop

Comment: @Kotchi Added that as well

Answer (score 3):

Try like this (Instead of recursive function split and join):

```
def myRev(string):
    return ' '.join(string[::-1].split()[::-1])

print(myRev("Hello World"))
```